# Tricky trig integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I want to know how one should evaluate the following integral: $$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\cdot\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)} dx$$

It doesn't lend itself to substitution or integration by parts; I also haven't been able to find any "cheap shots" using properties of odd and even functions. I tried using Feynman's trick with it, but it doesn't seem very helpful here (where to introduce the arbitrary variable other than in the power on cosine?).

I want to know how to solve this integral, but also more broadly, if there is any transferrable skill/trick I can learn from it. I am also interested in how one can discern which integrals are good candidates for Feynman's trick.

Comment: Whenever I see in the denominator an $x$ multiplied by something, e.g. $\int_a^b \frac{f(tx)}{x g(x)}dx$, I like to differentiate with respect to a parameter, say $t$, so that I could get rid of the $x$ and evaluate a possibly easier expression like $\int_a^b \frac{f'(xt)}{g(x)}dx$.

Comment: Notice that if the $x$ wasn't there you would want to do $u=\cos x$. But the extra $x$ is a bit annoying. To get rid of it, you can do partial integration, which will give you a bit work to integrate $\frac{\sin x}{1+\cos^2x}$ but nothing too complex, that should give you an easier integral (I think). That's what I would try.

Comment: @Accelerator I agree, but I don't see how that would be applicable here. $x$ is in the numerator right?

Comment: @VincentBatens Yes, but at the end of the post, the OP was asking how one could discern what expressions could be worth differentiating under the integral. In fact, I could have changed my first comment to where I had $\int_a^b \frac{f(t h(x))}{h(x) g(x)}dx$ instead and differentiating with respect to $t$ could be a worthy trick.

Comment: Ah okay, it indeed is a very usefull trick.

Comment: My approach does not work. It gives you an ugly integral that's left.

Comment: Some of the methods shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1621215/calculate-int-0-pi-frac-x1-cos2xdx/) (same integral without $\sin$) may also be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Integrating $\int^0_\pi \frac{x \sin x}{1+\cos^2 x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323109/integrating-int0-pi-fracx-sin-x1-cos2-x) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_%7B0%7D%5E%7B%5Cpi%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ccdot%5Ctext%7Bsin%7D(x)%7D%7B1%2B%5Ctext%7Bcos%7D%5E2(x)%7Ddx%24&p=1). Note another duplicate is [Evaluate $\int^{\pi}_0\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}dx$](/q/3608052), and also ...

Comment: (cont.) [Why can we redefine the definition of a variable during substitution? Or let say assume it has two different values](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3061277) is very similar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $x = \pi-u$. Then

$\displaystyle I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\cdot\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)}\, dx = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi-u)\cdot\text{sin}(u)}{1+\text{cos}^2(u)}\,du = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi-x)\cdot\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)}\,dx$

So that

$\displaystyle 2I = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{x\cdot\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)}\, dx +\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{(\pi-x)\cdot\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)}\, dx = \pi \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\text{sin}(x)}{1+\text{cos}^2(x)}\, dx$

The last integral should be routine to calculate (e.g. let $t = \cos{x}$).

Answer (score 7):

**Symmetry**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\pi\frac{(\pi-x)\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1a}\\
&=\frac\pi2\int_0^\pi\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1b}\\
&=\left.-\frac\pi2\arctan(\cos(x))\,\right|_0^\pi\tag{1c}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\tag{1d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(1a):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\pi-x$
$\text{(1b):}$ average both sides of $\text{(1a)}$
$\text{(1c):}$ $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(\cos(x))=-\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}$
$\text{(1d):}$ evaluate

---

**Integration by Parts**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\pi\frac{x\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^\pi x\,\mathrm{d}\arctan(\cos(x))\tag{2a}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4+\int_0^\pi\arctan(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2b}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4-\int_0^\pi\arctan(\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2c}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}4\tag{2d}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\arctan(\cos(x))=-\frac{\sin(x)}{1+\cos^2(x)}$
$\text{(2b):}$ integrate by parts
$\text{(2c):}$ substitute $x\mapsto\pi-x$
$\text{(2d):}$ average $\text{(2b)}$ and $\text{(2c)}$

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int_0^\pi \frac{x \sin x}{1 + \cos^2x} \, dx \\
&= \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\left(y+\frac\pi2\right) \cos y}{1+\sin^2y} \, dy & x=y+\frac\pi2 \\
&= \frac\pi2 \int_{-\tfrac\pi2}^{\tfrac\pi2} \frac{\cos y}{1+\sin^2y} \, dy & \text{parity}\\
&= \frac\pi2 \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dz}{1+z^2} & z=\sin y
\end{align*}$$